# Javascript and Ajax Load more on page scroll: not loading more on smart phones running android or ios

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this javascript and ajax code that loads more data from the database on page scroll to the bottom. It works very well on desktop and laptops. However, there seems to be a problem when loading from smartphones. It loads the first 10 items and doesn't load more on page scroll like the desktop. It doesn't throw any error nor make an alert. It just doesn't load more no matter what I do or how I position the screen.

```
var page_num = 1;
var loading  = false;
load_more_contents(page_num);
$(window).scroll(function() {
if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height()) {
    page_num++;
    load_more_contents(page_num);
}
});     
function load_more_contents(page_num){
if(loading == false){
    loading = true;
    $('.loading-info').show();
    $.post('load_more_videos.php', {'page': track_page}, function(data){
        loading = false;
        if(data.trim().length == 0)
        {
            $('.loading-info').html('<p> End of records</p>');
            return;
 }
$('.loading-info').hide();

$("#results").append(data);
}).fail(function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { 
        alert(thrownError);
    })
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution. To those whom it might help in the future. Essentially you just need to offset the bottom of the page so to speak.  As the user is scrolling you want the next lot to load not at the bottom of the page but just above it (note the -100)

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
 if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height()-100) {
page_num++;
load_more_contents(page_num);
}
});
```

Here's a demo: http://jsbin.com/humiwek/edit?js,console,output